# Ant build keeps saying class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0

Tags: java, windows, ant, version

I set 1.6 java for a legacy project ant build, and I am really running out any idea what can be wrong

Here is what I see:

java -version

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-2
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

javac -version:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-2
javac 1.6.0_45
```

while building ant:

```
 [echo] Java/JVM version: 1.6
 [echo] Java/JVM detail version: 1.6.0_45
```

It seems to be correctly in environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45'
PATH = ...'%JAVA_HOME%\bin'... (note, I tried with full path too, no progress)
```

I checked Windows\system32, no other versions there

I even reinstalled Java 1.6 to make sure it is not spoiled.

After all these Ant build keeps saying class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0, what else can be wrong?

Comment: It looks like your ant script uses some classes/libraries compiled with JDK 1.8 .

Comment: I will update the question, because it is complaining on one of my class

Comment: Actually you were right!
I think I compiled once with 1.8 and it wasn't cleaned.